# Time complexity for recursion

Tags: python, time-complexity

How to count the time complexity (Big O) for these recursion functions?

```
def function3(value, number):
    if (number == 0):
        return 1
    elif (number == 1):
        return value
    else:
        half = number // 2
        result = function3(value, half)
        if (number % 2 == 0):
            return result * result
        else:
            return value * result * result
```

Comment: you could add what you tried

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What have you already tried, and what do you need help with exactly? We're not here to do your work for you. Do you know how to calculate big-O yourself? If so, what could you figure out when you tried to apply it to this function? Please read [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the Big O, you need to set up the correct equation of the time, i.e.

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + O(1)
     = T(n/4) + 2*O(1)
     =...
     = T(n/(2^i)) + Σ_k = (1-> i)(O(1))
```

With n/(2^i) ~= 1 --> i ~= Log2(n)

```
T(n) ~= Log2(n)*O(1) = O(Log(n))
```

Read more at [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Answer (score 0):

Look for the *update* in your recursive function. Ho quickly oes the function converge on one of the base cases that break the recursion?

Addition or subtraction used to converge would give a linear result, or O(n). But here you're updating exponentially.

```
half = number // 2
result = function3(value, half)
```

You divide by `2`, then pass that value to a place where it will again be divided by `2` on the next call.

This leads to logarithmic growth, or O(log n).

Consider calling `function3(2, 8)`:

```
function(2, 8)
function(2, 4)
function(2, 2)
function(2, 1)
```

If we double `n` by calling `function(2, 16)` the function will only execute one additional time.